# How can I check whether the numpy array exists already or not?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to know if an array is already defined somewhere before in the code.
Something like `a.exist()` gives True if it exists and False if it doesn't.

I tried `a.size:`, but if the array doesn't exist yet, it gives an error message, which I want to avoid.

The situation demanding this happened in a loop, if you are wondering.

Comment: You could wrap that in `try` `except` scope

Comment: What about `if a:` or `if "a" in vars():`?

Comment: How do you not know what is defined? Sounds very much like something is wrong in your logic

Comment: It could be a situation where you have a queue that keeps being fed with numpy arrays and you want to continue only until you are popping an empty element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python has some builtin-functions that can ckeck if a variable is assigned in the current/local/global scope.

For example to check if a variable is defined in the current local scopy use:

```
if 'a' in dir():
    # Variable a is defined.
    if hasattr(a, 'shape'):
        # Probably a numpy array, at least it has a shape.
```

But that's not good python, `try/except` is more common but for completness I thought it worth mentioning that you can do it without any try/except.

```
if 'a' in dir():
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
# prints 'no' because we haven't defined any variable a

a = np.array([1,2,3])
if 'a' in dir():
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
# prints 'yes' because I defined it

del a
if 'a' in dir():
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
# prints 'no' because I deleted the variable again
```

Also worth mentioning is [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) and [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals).

Answer (score 9):

You'll need to use a try/except block:

```
try:
    _ = a.shape
except NameError:
    print('a does not exist.')
except AttributeError:
    print('a does not have a shape property.')
```

As @padraic points out, this really shouldn't occur in the first place.  It is best to initialize your variables (e.g. `a = None`) and then check that they have been set (e.g. `if a: print('a is set') else: print('a has not been set')`)

Comment: Perfect. But, as pointed out, I think I will rewrite my code so that situation doesn't happen in the first place.

Comment: The problem with this is that if you're writing `if a:` where `a` is an array, it will try to evaluate all the entries in `a`, and return an error: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: @ArturJ That was just an e.g. (for example), not a specific case.  One would probably set the default value to `None` and then test `if a is not None`.

Answer (score 5):

In case you want to be sure that `a` is a `numpy` array and not any other type that may have a `size` variable or method, you can check the type warped in a try block to handle the exception in case the variable is not defined. This way you go ahead only if `a` exists and is a `numpy` array.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2])
try:
    if isinstance(b,np.ndarray):
        print("TRUE")
except NameError:
    print("FALSE")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a `try/except NameError` wrapper is good Python.  But initializing the variable to something useful before hand is equally good.  I don't think there's much of difference in speed, but the code is more readable.

For example:

```
for i in range(5):
    a += 4
```

will produce a

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

which can be trapped with:

```
for i in range(5):
    try:
        a += 4
    except NameError:
        a = np.arange(5)
```

But I could define `a` earlier. `None` is a handy value if I don't know before hand what the first value of `a` should be:

```
a=None
for i in range(5):
   if a is None:
       a=np.arange(5)
   a += 4
```

Another common `numpy` practice is to start with an empty list, and accumulate values there.

```
a = []
for i in range(5):
    a.append(np.ones(4)*i)
a = np.array(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The phrase 'is not None' is a good catchall for determining the existence or non-existence of arrays.

```
if (a is not None):
    #Do something if it exists
else:
    #Do something if it does not exist
```