# How to check whether a numpy.array exists or not ? Truth testing value for numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, isinstance

While developing a class that uses `numpy.array`, I'd like to construct this array at one stage, and later check whether it exists in order to manipulate it, or construct it at a later stage (pseudo-code below). How could I check that this array exists ?

For any basic object, I use : `if my_object: # do something` which uses the [truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), but for `numpy` the [truth value testing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.logic.html) checks whether any or all elements of the array is present, so `if my_array: # do something` gives the error `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`.

At the moment, the only working turn-around is to call `isinstance(my_array,numpy.ndarray)`, but I think this is not really convenient (especially because some librairies like `sklearn` can turn numpy array to `scipy.sparse` objects for instance).

The pseudo-code to illustrate what I'd like to do :

```py
def compute_my_array(self, ...):
   # long job here
   return my_array

def new_computation(self, my_array = None, ...):
   if not my_array: # if my_array does not exist, compute it ...
      my_array = compute_my_array(self, ...)
   do_something_else_with_my_array(my_array) # ... otherwise use it
```

For the moment the only way I found to check whether `my_array` exists is to use

```py
   if not isinstance(my_array, numpy.ndarray):
      my_array = compute_my_array(my_array)
```

Is there any other (perhaps better) ways to do that check ?

Comment: Obviously, `if my_array is not None` does the job... is there any more pythonic way to go over this problem ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check whether the numpy array exists already or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541595/how-can-i-check-whether-the-numpy-array-exists-already-or-not)

Comment: `if my_array is None:` (which is what you want there) is perfectly pythonic

Comment: @DanielF Yes it is, but my main problem is whether a numpy array or a scipy.sparse matrix is empty or not, so it's not really the same problem. But surely I can use that trick. Thank you.

Comment: @amzon-ex Thank you for pointing to this anwser. It doesn't really solve my problem, since I'd like to know whether an object that could be either a scipy.sparse or a numpy.array is empty or not. But yes, going though the object.shape check can be an option. I'm nevertheless looking for something more direct.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your default to return an empty array, and then check if there's anything in the array

```
def new_computation(self, my_array = np.zeros((1,)), ...):
   if not my_array.any(): # if my_array has no nonzero data, compute it ...
      my_array = compute_my_array(self, ...)
   do_something_else_with_my_array(my_array) # ... otherwise use it
```